# Hibernate - How to ignore a not mapped field while insert

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Dear all hibernate developers,
The following hibernate hbm2java class I am using in my application. I need the **name** field while I am getting the data from database by join two tables. (This data I have to display in a grid in UI.)
However I am getting problem when I am trying insert a record into **rxJournal** table.
The error is:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'
```

I want to ignore/skip the 'name' filed While insert or update a record by using hibernate.
Following is my HBM class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rxJournal", catalog = "Company")
public class RxJournalBean implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer rxJournalId;
private String entryMemo;
private String name;

    ....

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "rxJournalID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getRxJournalId() {return this.rxJournalId;}
public void setRxJournalId(Integer rxJournalId) {this.rxJournalId = rxJournalId;}

@Column(name = "EntryMemo")
public String getEntryMemo() {return this.entryMemo;}
public void setEntryMemo(String entryMemo) {this.entryMemo = entryMemo;}

public String getName() {return name;}
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
}
```

I can create another bean by removing name field alone, however I don't want to use redundant code. Kindly give me any suggestions.

Please ignore if I am asking any repeated question and point me to right solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to have a name property in your entity, but you would like this property to be non-persistent (i.e. completely ignored by Hibernate).

If so, that's what @Transient is for:

```
@Transient
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

The name property will of course be null for every instance loaded by Hibernate from the database. It will only have a value if you assign one.

Comment: Hai @JB Nizet, thanks a lot. Yes, that is what exactly what I am looking for. You helped me.

Comment: Hai @JB Nizet, your solution "@Transient" is working fine in my local and testing servers. However when I move to production I am getting error. I guess I am missing some jar. I am having "persistance-api.1.0.jar" and "hibernate-core.3.6.10.final.jar" in my "pom.xml". Please suggest If I am missing any thing.

Comment: Ask another question, where you show your pom, the exact error message, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Hai @JB Nizet, I have asked the new question. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631894/transient-not-working-fine-conflicting-with-other-jars).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631894/transient-not-working-fine-conflicting-with-other-jars